# The Server State which error_logger print, is the State when handling "Last message in was"?

Tags: erlang, gen-server

forgive my poor English,

I mean when a gen_server crash, the error_logger print `"Last message in was"` and `"When Server State"`, The Server State value is the state before handle the Last message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a gen_server, the state is stored by the generic part of the code, which is supposed to be robust. It is changed by callback functions which have to return the new state value as their result.

When the system reports an error, the state reported is the one passed as parameter to the callback who is responsible for the crash.